# If statement based on time ago in words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to do something that I thought would be very simple, and I can get it to work in console but not in my controller properly.

In the create action of my controller, I have a post to facebook and twitter portion of my create action.  I want this part to trigger IF the user has no posts OR IF the last post was created greater than 10 minutes ago.

So basically, if posts are blank, or if last post was > 10 minutes ago, POST to FB and Twitter.

What is wrong with this if statement?

```
if current_user.posts.blank? || current_user.posts.last.created_at < 10.minutes.ago
   do post stuff
end
```

Right now nothing is posting even when i sign in as an user who has no posts.

I can get the true/false result of the 2nd portion working properly in console.

Any ideas?

Comment: you said "if last post was > 10 minutes ago" but you have less than in your posted snippet

Comment: i played with this.  it's counter intuitive but a time posted 20 minutes ago is less than a time posted now, so i think it is right.  if my last post's time stamp is less than the time at exactly 10 minutes ago, post.

Comment: It is not counter intuitive - if sth happened more then 10 minutes ago, it happened before the time 10 minutes ago. It seems that there is problem with the data you are using, not the condition itself.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code that you posted, what makes you think it's got anything to do with that condition? The only thing not quite right about it is that `current_user.posts.last` isn't necessarily going to select the most recent post, unless you have some default scoping going on.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what it could be.  The most simple test is when I log in as a new user, they have 0 posts.  That should immediately satisfy the first condition in the or statement, yet it doesn't run the code within it.  When i take out the if/end, it works fine.

Comment: @MikeCampbell i would think the .last would be most recent, or the last one that they posted. No?  Is there a better way to do this?  Need a custom model scope?

Comment: As Mike said "could be a scoping issue", try forcing the order: current_user.posts.order('created_at ASC').last... and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Oh.. and yes, create a relevant scope but also create a "can_post_to_social_media?" method on the user so you can write some unit tests around the logic.

Comment: The code you posted seems fine, but you say you're calling this in your create action. Could it be you're creating a new post before this (thus invalidating both conditions)?

Comment: @rlecaro2 that has to be it.  good catch.  i'll play with it and make that the answer if so.  this all comes after my save action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was my if condition was after the post saved, so even if it was an users first post the count was at 1 by the time it reached my if statement.  thank you @rlecaro2.  I changed my code to this to fix.

```
if current_user.posts.count - 1 == 0 || current_user.posts[-2].created_at < 20.minutes.ago
```

Comment: Just a small tip: `current_user.posts.empty?` is a more readable approach to the first condition

Comment: Glad to be of use @brad, remember to accept your own answer. Some thoughts: maybe you could use your original conditions in a `before_action` method (making them work as intended)? What if a user deletes posts and gets to have 1 (but not his first)? You could check `count == 1` :/. I don't really know what you're trying to achieve but maybe there's a better way to do it (or at least a more maintainable one). GL & HF.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with mini refactoring:

```
# Caching
posts = current_user.posts

# Let's check
if posts.blank? || (!posts.blank? && posts.last.created_at < 10.minutes.ago)
  # do post stuff
end
```